# Pyotp not giving the same code as Google authenticator even with URI

Tags: python, google-authenticator, google-2fa

Hi there Stackoverflow users.

I tried using Python to use the 2FA Secret on Stripe to get the 2FA Code.
But each time I try the codes are`nt the same as if I used Google authenticator.
I Aleardy tried using a uri, but without any luck. I already checked Stackoverflow if maybe someone else had the same issue, I found one person who had, but his solution sadly did not work for me. I hope anyone can help me through this.

My current code:

```py
def makeotpauth(email, secret):
    emailquoted = quote("Stripe: " + email)
    otpauth = "otpauth://totp/" + emailquoted + "?secret=" + secret + "&issuer=Stripe"
    totp = pyotp.parse_uri(otpauth)
    return totp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: The Windows time was not in sync, it was running 2 Minutes late.
To check this go to [HERE](https://time.is).